# Where is a list of Entity Framework's unsupported types?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, code-first, scaffolding

Either I am blind, or there is no published/searchable list of C# types that Entity Framework skips or does not support when building a code-first database.  If I am blind, please lead me.  Else, please link me - and everyone else who cannot locate this important documentation omission.

Using several variations on the search terms ***"entity framework" "code first" type not supported***, I found only obsolete and incomplete references, usually dated 2009 or earlier.  I tried asking several MVPs directly - all of whom list C#, VS, MVC, and/or EF as one of their specialties - to no avail.  In the absence of comprehensive & current search results and responses from any of them, I wonder if this documentation exists.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *scalar types* that Entity Framework supports are [defined in the Entity Data Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee382832(v=vs.110).aspx). In addition to scalars, *complex types* (made up of scalars or other complex types) are also supported.

So basically instead of the blacklist that the question asks for, you have a whitelist:

```
Binary
Boolean
Byte
DateTime
DateTimeOffset
Decimal
Double
Float
Guid
Int16
Int32
Int64
SByte
String
Time
```

Comment: I understand this as: All types unsupported, except {your list}.  Is that accurate?  I'm double-checking, because the vStudio library includes, *"Typically, primitive data types in the EDM are mapped to corresponding primitive data types in the storage or hosting environment."*  Use of **"Typically"** didn't strike me as technically exclusive.

Comment: @SierraMultimedia: I'm not sure what "typically" wants to convey, but if you think about the intersection of BCL and SQL types you will agree it isn't that large. To the best of my knowledge, these are what you have to work with.

Comment: Excellent; then that's what I'll go on.  I'll mark this answered.